# Original mathematical foundation of Dirac's function

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, dirac

In which paper/book (most likely) by either Sobolev or Schwartz is the Dirac function properly and explicitly substantiated as a functional (tempered distribution), preferably quoting Dirac's name? I need to know the oldest (the original) source, in order to quote it as a remark in an article that I'm writing on the history of mathematical foundations of Dirac's inventions (Delta function and bra-kets).

Comment: Schwartz  L., *Généralisation de la notion de fonction et de dérivation théorie des distributions*, Annales Des Télécommunications vol. 3, p.135–140 (1948):  a plausible place (online Springer)

Comment: Sobolev had papers in 1936 and 1938 in which he introduced "generalized functions" and also proved his imbedding theorems. Surely that did include Dirac's function... but the Math Reviews accounts (unsurprisingly) do not talk about the papers from that viewpoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found another, [later paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82190991.pdf) which also references the Schwartz item that @sand1 commented as well as another paper by Schwartz from 1945.
The reference paper is:

> Historia Mathematics 10 (1983) 149-183  DISTRIBUTIONS: THE EVOLUTION
> OF A MATHEMATICAL THEORY  BY JOHN SYNOWIEC  INDIANA UNIVERSITY
> NORTHWEST, GARY, INDIANA 46408

The references listed therein include

> Schwartz, L. 1944. Sur certaines families non fondamentales de
> fonctions continues.  Bulletin de la Société Mathematique de France
> 72, 141-145.
>
> - 1945. Généralisation de la notion de fonction, de dérivation, de transformation de Fourier et applications mathematiques et
>         physiques. Annales de l'Université de Grenoble 21, 57-74.
>         -- 1947-1948. Theorie des distributions et transformations de Fourier. Annales  de l'université de Grenoble 23, 7-24.
> - 1948. Généralisation de la notion de fonction et de dérivation. Théorie de  distributions. Annales Télécommunications 3, 135-140.

and many more.

Comment: I accepted this answer as the one I was looking for since the article of 1945 in AUG is the first one treating Dirac's 1926 invention as a functional in an explicit way.